# PHP make a variable have permanent value

Tags: php

I use a variable, value of which is a random string. Every time I refresh the page, that string changes. All good but I need to echo also the random string that was also generated before the new refresh, in other words store that string into a permanent let's say variable. Example: `12345` is generated, reload, `abcde` is generated but I want `12345` to be echoed as well... How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Do you hear the [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) screaming ? Use `$_SESSION` array. You have to start your session with `session_start()` **on every page where you want to use it** then you can use this array: `$_SESSION` to store stuff over a new request on the server

Comment: When creating a variable out a random string, each time the page loads, it will do exactly as you describe.  Store the output into a session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put that variable value in the php [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

```
<?php session_start();
      $str = "";     
      if(!isset($_SESSION['var1']) || empty($_SESSION['var1']))
      {
          $str = ... // random a string
          $_SESSION['var1'] = str; // save in session 
      }
      else $str = $_SESSION['var1']; // get the value back from session
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Also on the logout time, instead of deleting the whole session global variable, you should delete the specific session.

```
session_unset($_SESSION['specific_session']);
```